# Can group functionality be used for grouping two different classes?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Suppose I have two scripts say script1.java and script2.java in the same package. Now I want to run @test annotations of both the scripts.Can I do it by using groups in testNG?

Answer (score 0):

@Groups annotation will group 2 or more testcases in a group (regression test group / functional testcase group/ UI test group/Sanity Testcase group)

@Test(groups = {"sanity", "regression"} )
public void testMethod1() {
}

@Test(groups = {"sanity", "functional"} )
public void testMethod2() {
}

Means if you run sanity group both testcases will run (may/may not be in order)

For your case:
You can use @BeforeTest annotation ( have it in script.java file) and then extends your scripts1.java and script2.java from script.java.
Then for both test scripts @BeforeTest will get call.

Hope it will helpful

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rely on groups if you want only some of the @Test annotated tests to run.  If you want all the @Test annotated methods of both ur scripts to run, then you can use the classes tag, something like :

```
 <test name="Simple example">

  <classes>
    <class name="package.script2/>
    <class name="package.script1"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

Refer  [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methods) to understand more about groups.